# When should I use function vs method?

Tags: function, oop, functional-programming

Lets say I have some inputs and I'm generating some output.
I don't need to maintain state.

Should I use a function or should I create a class that will have one method that 
would look exactly like that function?

What are the advantages of one over the other?
(besides unit testing which is easier with the object)

Comment: "besides unit testing which is easier with the object" - how so?

Comment: It's very much the same. Imagining you don't do mutation in any of them a method is a function where the first argument is predetermined (an instance of a class). eg `append(str1, str2)` and `str1.append(str2)` can do the same thing. In Common Lisp it's even more the same than other languages as methods implementations are chosen on the signatures of all arguments and not just the first.

Comment: @daniel-earwicker To mock a function that you call, you need something like test hooks, but to mock a class, you just have to create the MockClass that inherit from your class and pass an instance of that with dependency injection.

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz - any half-decent language will let you pass functions-as-values to other functions, so there is literally zero distinction between a function and a stateless class with one method.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a Java background, this question is like asking if you should create a `static final` "Utils" class, a service class to inject, or a "smart" data carrier with behaviour.

Just as a personal opinion, generally, if the methods truly are stateless, it's just easier and simpler to create a `static final` "utils" class.

But as someone pointed out in the comments above, it's as broad as long, really.